# If $x$ and $y$ are integers then prove that $(-x)+(-y)=-(x+y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, proof-writing, arithmetic, integers

> If $x$ and $y$ are integers then prove that $(-x)+(-y)=-(x+y)$

---

My attempt:

I did google, and also it may be theorem itself. If we take common $'-'$ then itself proved itself in one line. Although, I don't its formal proof.

> Can you explain it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$-(x+y)=(-1)(x+y)=(-1)(x)+(-1)(y)=(-x)+(-y)$

Comment: @Mithlesh Upadhyay Just I would like to add that your question has not required a solution by using minimal number of (axiomatic) assumptions. In general, such requirement could make a solution very long (for any problem). I just used this statement $-x=(-1)x$, which makes the solution very simple, short and clear.

Answer (score 2):

The argument will depend on what is assumed.

At the most basic level, $-z $ denotes the (unique) number such that $-z+z=0$. So the equality  $(-x)+(-y)=-(x+y) $ can (should, possibly) be read as saying the $(-x)+(-y) $ is the additive inverse of $x+y $; that is,$-(x+y) $. So, here, one needs to check that
\begin{align}
[(-x)+(-y)]+(x+y)&=(-x)+(-y)+(y+x)=(-x)+[(-y)+y ]+x\\ \ \\
&=(-x)+0+x=(-x)+x=0
\end{align}

In terms of axioms and properties, this comes before of the equality  $-z=(-1)z $ (which usually requires a proof on its own).

Comment: +1 for the argument using minimal assumption - essentially just the (abelian) group under addition.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Actually, the question has not required a solution by using minimal number of (axiomatic) assumptions. In general, such requirement could make a solution very long (for any problem). I just used this statement $-x=(-1)x$, which makes the solution very simple and clear.

Comment: @J.Pak I agree. I upvoted your answer too.